Excel INDIRECT - how to return (or concatenate) multiple ranges
The use of INDIRECT when a range is specified (i.e. INDIRECT("H2:H5")) results in an array of values -- in the case of my example, I get 4 values. What I would like to do is to create an array of values resulting from multiple ranges.
I tried INDIRECT("H2:H5, H10:H15"), but Excel complained. Is there a way to do this, with ArrayFormulas perhaps, where I can combine ranges in a single cell formula so the resulting array of values is the concatenated values specified in the range(s)?

Why are you doing INDIRECT("H2:H5") and not just =H2:H5?  But to answer your question VSTACK is what you want.

To elaborate Scott's answer nesting the formulas as =Vstack( INDIRECT("H2:H5"), INDIRECT("H10:H15") ) or =Vstack(H2:H5,H10:H15)
